# Problem Box-Cox Transformation on Multiple Linear Models

Tags: r, stata

When I use the command `bcskew0` in Stata and I compare with the command `boxcox` of MASS library outputs in R, there's a massive difference.

Here are my data:

```
tempo <- c(61, 43, 35, 32, 60, 32, 69, 63, 62, 66, 49, 69, 50, 67, 67, 35, 62, 42, 38, 47, 65, 49, 30, 52, 55, 56, 58, 66, 33, 34, 66, 33, 60, 70, 55, 62, 34, 32, 53, 52, 61, 43, 35, 32, 60, 32, 69, 63, 62, 66)

dist <- c(34, 36, 18, 22, 40, 24, 40, 40, 40, 38, 36, 40, 40, 40, 38, 12, 40, 38, 40, 38, 38, 38, 18, 38, 38, 38, 38, 40, 18, 20, 38, 32, 38, 38, 38, 38, 28, 36, 40, 40, 34, 36, 18, 22, 40, 24, 40, 40, 40, 38)

sem <- c(11, 3, 3, 9, 16, 0, 13, 19, 11, 16, 5, 18, 15, 19, 12, 5, 11, 3, 16,  7, 12, 11, 3, 9, 10, 11, 11, 17, 8, 5, 14, 7, 12, 16, 15, 12, 1, 9, 15, 15, 11, 3, 3, 9, 16, 0, 13, 19, 11, 16)
```

On Stata, I've tried:

```
reg tempo dist sem
```

Then:

```
bcskew0 bctempo = tempo
```

And finally:

```
reg bctempo dist sem
```

On Stata, the Box-Cox transformation reports that the lambda value was 2.6486.

Now the R commands and outputs

```
model <- lm(tempo ~ dist + sem, database)
library(MASS)
bc <- boxcox(model, lambda = seq(-3,3))
opt.lambda <- bc$x[whitch(bc$y == max(bc$y))]
```

Then I'm using the value of `opt.lambda` object to transform my dependent variable. But, even so, the Stata lambda value is very different from the R lambda value.

Could anyone help me to understand the differences in outputs?

Comment: Is `whitch()` correct or a typo?

Answer (score 2):

You are not comparing like with like.

In Stata the results of `bcskew0` depend on what you give it, just the marginal distribution of `tempo` as a single variable. That is not presented in conjunction with any predictors.

`tempo` is slightly left-skewed. `bcskew0` suggests a transformation with a power of 2.65, which out of context sounds quite a strong transformation.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     n = 50 |       mean          SD    skewness    kurtosis
----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
(tempo^2.648597-1)/2.648597 |  14923.004    8653.249      -0.000       1.563
                      tempo |     51.740      13.465      -0.327       1.590
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, positively, results show that `bcskew0` does achieve what you ask of it, which is to produce a zero skewness transform.

[image]

But a plot (above) shows that given the limited range of `tempo` the transformation isn't a big deal.

On this evidence, I wouldn't transform `tempo` at all. I don't know what `tempo` means or measures, but I have no reason to believe that a power of 2.65 makes more sense than the original scale of `tempo`. The reduction in skewness does not seem even a compensating benefit for the loss of easy interpretation. In any case I don't much mind about marginal distributions out of context of the model I am seeking.

`boxcox()` in R by comparison is looking at the entire dataset, of a response and two predictors. Here the game is quite different,  whether a transformed scale would be a better story for the relationship between response and predictors. From plots of the response and the predictors separately, the relationship with `dist` seems particularly odd, which needs some kind of story, but `regress` results overall in Stata don't seem too bad.

[image]

In Stata it would be `boxcox` that you would use to try to go further. `bcskew0` can't help directly with looking for a better model. Otherwise put, a transformation that "helps" with distribution shape isn't necessarily one that helps with a predictive relationship.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!

I was trying to figure out the difference between the outputs (Stata anda R), and now I did.

The database is fictitious and has educational purposes only.

Could you tell me, please, if you know a R command that returns this outputs in a similar way to Stata?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use R enough to advise. Stata I use more.

Comment: Thank you anyway (: